# slideshow using html not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have gone through the answer posted earlier on this website but my slideshow does not work and shows the first image always. 
Below is my code

```
<div id= slideshow>
<img class ='imagem_artigo' src="/images1/coveover.jpg" name="Myslide"  width=750;                height=300 align="middle">
<script type="text/javascript">
var step = 1;
var img1 = new Image();
img.src = "/images1/tecover.jpg";
var img2 = new Image();
img2.src = "/images1/te.jpg";
var img3 = new Image();
img3.src = "/images1/te1.jpg";
var img4 = new Image();
img4.src = "/images1/im7.jpg";

function slideshow(){
document.images.Myslide.src = eval("img" + step+".src");
if(step<=4)
    step++;
else
    step = 1;
setTimeout(function(){slideshow()},1000);
}
slideshow();
</script >
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building sliders it's better to write the majority of what you want to show in the DOM so it'll load and search engines can find it etc.

Here's what I would do

```
<div id="imageSlider">
    <div class="imageSliderContainer clearfix">
        <div class="article">
            <img src="/images1/coverover.jpg" width="" height="" alt="write stuff here etc" title="">
        </div>
        <div class="article">
            <img src="/images1/tecover.jpg" width="" height="" alt="" title="">
        </div>
        <div class="article">
            <img src="/images1/te.jpg" width="" height="">
        </div>
        <div class="article">
            <img src="/images1/te1.jpg" width="" height="">
        </div>
        <div class="article">
            <img src="/images1/im7.jpg" width="" height="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

using alt and title will mean your html will be wc3 compliant ;) also the image can be found using an internet search :) or whatever

Now you wanna build a slideshow huh? I'll show you some cool CSS to get you going first then I'll come back to the javascript :p

first off, we want to make sure people who haven't got javascript enabled are able to view your images don't we? So lets make a nice scroll window looking thingy for those special paranoid people with no javascript :p

```
#imageSlider{overflow:auto;}
```

Now anything that's over 100% width of `#imageSlider` will be scrollable.
I've used classes called articles. The reason I've done this will become much clearer later :) but for now this is simply why.

There are 5 articles and you want each to be 100% of the parent so that the others aren't showing when you're on that image right? So 5*100=500

```
.imageSliderContainer{width:500%;}
```

100/5=20

```
.imageSliderContainer .article{width:20%;float:left;}
.clearfix:after{clear:both;display:block;visibility:hidden;content:'';}
```

Now each article/image will be 100% width of the parent so they won't be visible when one is selected :p

and the clearfix and float will make the articles inline with each other :) without causing conflicts with other elements

Next we want to make sure our images look cool inside the article. and they're properly positioned and sized so they're not outside of the container etc.

```
.imageSliderContainer .article img{max-width:100%;height:auto;display:inline-block;}
.imageSliderContainer .article{width:20%;text-align:center;background:#000000;}
```

now things should be starting to look rather nice and smooth right? IF you're still following :p

Next comes the javascript. I'm more fluent in jQuery but I'll give examples of both just incase :)

First off we want to turn off the scrolling

```
$('#imageSlider').css({'overflow':'hidden'});/*jquery*/
document.getElementById('imageSlider').style.overflow="hidden";/*javascript*/
```

Next we want to make the images 'change' when really what I'm going to do is scroll the element along so we can see the next one ;p 
Some people like to use a negative margin left but some designers are like "AGHHHH NEGATIVE VALUES" for some reason so I'll just use scrollLeft instead :p

this is where it's ganna get a little complicated. First you want to get the current location of the container's scrollLeft then adjust it.

```
/*jQuery*/
function nextSlide(){
    var sliderScroll=$('#imageSlider').scrollLeft();
    var artWid=$('.article').width();
    var artQuant=$('.article').length;
    var next=0-(sliderScroll==((artQuant-1)*artWid))?0(sliderScroll+artWid);
    $('#imageSlider').animate({scrollLeft:next},500);  
}
/*javascript*/
function nextSlideA() {
     var slider=document.getElementById('imageSlider');
     var art=document.getElementsByClassName('article');
     var next=0-(slider.scrollLeft==((art.length-1)*art[0].offsetWidth()))?0:(art[0].offsetWidth()+slider.scrollLeft);
     document.getElementById('position').innerHTML=next;
     slider.scrollLeft = next;
}
```

the variable next will equal 0 if you're on the last image and will go to the next image if you're in the middle of the slideshow :)

Javascript won't look as fancy as jQuery but it'll get the job done. I'm sorry if I've made any mistakes I'm currently on the phone as I'm writing this, let me know if something doesn't work and I'll fix it :)

Next just simply call the function using your `setInterval();`

```
var slider=setInterval(function(){nextSlide();},1000);
```

And job done :) Hope this was helpful! I'll make a quick jsfiddle for you so you can see how it all works :) 
http://jsfiddle.net/s6crzzfr/

Comment: The image doesn't change in the jsfiddle sketch no matter how I interact with it... what am I missing? I tried latest Chrome and Safari, js enabled.